# Can I create an array of a parent class that contains its subclasses and then apply subclass methods to the array?

Tags: java, arrays, parent-child

In java, can I create an array of a parent class that contains its subclasses. Then after that, can I apply the methods found in the subclass to the object in the array.

For example,

```
Animal[] c =new Animal[6]; 

c[0] = new Dog(new Animal()); 
 
c[0].setBreedOfDog("Pug")
```

In this, I create an parent array using Animal, and then put in the subclass Dog into it. But when I try to use a setter in the Dog class, I get an error. **Can't I do this with pointers?** Can anyone tell me why this is. Thank you.

Comment: Because the array is declared as an `Animal[]`, in other words: according to the type of the variable, the type of the elements in the array is `Animal` and not some specific subtype of `Animal`. This doesn't have anything to do with arrays; it's exactly the same as with 'normal' (non-array) variables.

Comment: You can check the runtime type of the array contents (e.g. with the instanceof operator) and cast to the resulting type. But this is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Because that's not how polymorphism works.

Comment: An `Animal` is not a `Dog`. A list of animals can include any animal, not just dogs. Calling `setBreedOfDog` only makes sense for a dog. *(Tangential: `setBreed` is sufficient--you already know it's a `Dog`, and `setBreed` is a general-purpose method that might belong on `Animal`)*.

Comment: You could abstract a method such as "setBreed" to Animal class, then you could call  Animal object's "setBreed" and actually invoke subclass's "Dog" method. This is polymorphism in Java.

Comment: Why are you putting an Animal in the dog instance? I assume a Dog is a subclass of Animal. Or are you not using inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to cast your array item to the representing class, `Dog`.

```java
Animal[] c = new Animal[6];
c[0] = new Dog();
((Dog) c[0]).setBreedOfDog("Pug");
```